# retrieve correct data in table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an iOS application that acts as a kind of email client. One of the views in my story board is an inbox in which displayed for each email: The sender of the message, the title of the conversation, the begining of the message body and the date & time at which the message was sent. (in tableView) 
I retrieve also the status of the message and I put these texts (sender, title) in bold if the message isn’t read yet( status=UNREAD) , and in normal style if the  message is read (status=READ).
The problem is, even if the status of fews messages is READ, it is set to bold.
this is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure Cell
     messageTableViewCell *cell = [self.mytableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[messageTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        reloadedMessage = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nom.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"sentBy"];
        cell.titre.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"messageThreadTitle"];
        cell.resume.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"messageBody"];
        cell.date.text = [reloadedMessage valueForKey:@"sentOn"];

    } else {
        currentMessage = [self.unreadmessagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.nom.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"sentBy"];
        cell.titre.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"messageThreadTitle"];
        cell.resume.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"messageBody"];
        cell.date.text = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"sentOn"];
        NSString *u = [currentMessage valueForKey:@"status"];
        if ([u isEqualToString:@"UNREAD"]) {
                [cell.titre setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];


          }
        }
        return cell;
    }
    `
```

And exemple of data :

```
   {
        messageBody = ":-)...";
        messageId = 643;
        messageThreadId = 529;
        messageThreadTitle = "dernier nstimer";
        sentBy = "IR  Maxim";
        sentOn = "2014-10-30 11:40:16";
        status = UNREAD;
    },
            {
        messageBody = "le timer...";
        messageId = 642;
        messageThreadId = 528;
        messageThreadTitle = nstimer;
        sentBy = "IR Maxim";
        sentOn = "2014-10-30 11:30:16";
        status = UNREAD;
    },
            {
        messageBody = "gras...";
        messageId = 639;
        messageThreadId = 525;
        messageThreadTitle = "mettre en gras";
        sentBy = "IR Maxim";
        sentOn = "2014-10-30 11:03:02";
        status = SENT;
    },
```

Any one have faced this problem or have an idea of what is the problem  ??

Comment: There is a whole lot of code duplication there. Remove the duplication and that will fix other bugs you have in the code (there are other bugs, even if you haven't noticed them yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set the font to bold, you never set it back. So if a reused cell happened to have bold text, it will still be bold the next time the text is used. Add an else clause that sets the font back to not-bold.

```
   if ([u isEqualToString:@"UNREAD"]) {
            [cell.titre setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
   }
   else {
       [cell.titre setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
   }
```

Comment: so what is the correction you suggest me in the code ?

Comment: Like I said, add an else clause to the if statement that sets the font to bold. In the else clause you should set the font to not-bold.

Comment: if ([u isEqualToString:@"UNREAD"]) {
                [cell.titre setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
        } else {
            [cell.titre setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9]];

        
        }

Comment: All I ask is that you mark the answer as correct. :-)

Comment: but, why in the search bar, i didn't need this ?  it worked whiteout else !! it is so strange

Comment: I've been burned by this more than once which is why I knew the answer so quickly. If you haven't seen the problem in the search bar yet, that's because the search bar hasn't tried reusing a cell yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data sources are messed up:

You have:

```
reloadedMessage = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And also:

```
currentMessage = [self.unreadmessagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

These are unlikely to be in sync with the indexPath you are asking for.

And if you are setting the bold font but not resetting it, you should at least reset the font to normal in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method, which is where you should reset all the cell's properties to their defaults.

Comment: yes, this because i used the search bar ...  thank you for your answer. i have set the else clause, it works now . thank you

Comment: now i want to set in normal style in didSelectRowAtIndexPath  method